# Android list files in specific zip folder

Tags: java, zip4j

I am trying to list files in a zip folder. I understand i can use the zip4j library or the java `ZipFile` class.

My question is using either of these tools, how can I list files in a given directory within the zip?

Comment: Why can't you use `ZipInputStream.getNextEntry()` ?

Comment: Have you read the JavaDocs for either of the lib?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to solve the task with just [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

```
final String folderNameToBrowse = "folder_name";
final String archivePath = "archive.zip";
final Path pathToBrowse = Paths.get(folderNameToBrowse);        

ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivePath));

ZipEntry temp = null;            
while ( (temp = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if(!temp.isDirectory()){
        Path currentPath = Paths.get(temp.getName());                    
        if(pathToBrowse.equals(currentPath.getParent())){
            // Here is the file name
            System.out.println(currentPath.getFileName());
        }
    }
}
```