# Get file from zip in file Internal Storage directory using path

Tags: android, file, kotlin, zip, android-internal-storage

I want to load a File from the Internal Storage file directory. I try to specify the path in this way:

```
File("${context.filesDir.absolutePath}/zipfile.zip/name.png")
```

but I receive the error: `No such file or directory`.

There is a way to specify the path of *name.png* without unzipping it with ZipFile class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android list files in specific zip folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383492/android-list-files-in-specific-zip-folder)

Comment: Very bad, it scan the zip to find a file every time it needs one. It needs to use ZipFile and ZipEntry class or use a future question of my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a way to specify the path of name.png without unzipping it with ZipFile class?

No, sorry. Android treats ZIP files fairly conventionally. If you want to access its contents, use `ZipFile`, `ZipInputStream`, or similar classes.